Pinescript - Compare price of Premarket with another close price
I want to trigger a function when two prices have the same value. Unfortunately, I can't do this.
Apparently the prices are not quite the same and I can't run the function. How can I solve this problem?
I tried it with a real-time candle and unfortunately it doesn't work:
if close == mywert
    label.new(bar_index, na, ""+ str.tostring(close), color=#f377ed, textcolor=color.black, style=label.style_label_up, yloc=yloc.belowbar, size = size.normal)


I would also be happy if the function was triggered in this price range, but how could I do this?

Make sure mywert is EXACTLY SAME as close. Including the same number of decimal places.

use ta.crossover it will help you to find when two price equel to each other returned true.
a = ta.crossover(close,mywert)
if a
//do what you need


Hey super thanks for the tipp!
